# How to count the number of keyword matched across the docs in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I have elastic search docs hosted in AWS managed services, I want to get the number of keywords present in the resultset. i.e lets say my docs have a textual data in a key and I am searching for keys X,Y,Z. it returns me an N number of docs. How can I get, how many times X is present in N docs, how many times Y is present and Z is present.
For e.g:
I have the following docs :

```
{
"id":1,
"date":"2019-04-24 12:10:05",
"text":"Hi I am from India and here for few days only",
"groupName":"India Toruist"
}

{
"id":2
"date":"2019-04-24 12:10:06",
"text":"Hi I am from Sri Lanka went to India in past and will stay here for 18 days only",
"groupName":"Sri Lanks Tourist"
}
```

Now I am searching for Sri Lanka and India against text key.It will return me both doc 1 and 2. I want how many time India has occurred and how many times Sri Lanka has occurred.

Comment: One option should be to use a custom ingest plugin e.g. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/geoip-processor.html#using-ingest-geoip the input is an IP but it allows you to search for a location. So the idea is that you calculate the metrics 'word' -> frequency and store it in another field.  Then you search for the word and you get back the metric. All the ability of ES searching depends on how the data is prepared.

Comment: Would [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) help or am I wrong with understanding the structure of your data?

Comment: Please provide your data structure as an example, and provide a example data set of what u want to archive to make it easiert to help you.

Comment: @aHochstein updated the question please find the updated question.

Comment: @TomášLinhart terms aggregation will not help, please look at the updated question

Comment: @Ibhagawati You write _...I am searching for Sri Lanka and India against text key..._ Can you post the actual query as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using aggregations. Below is the query which might help you.

```
    {
    "size": "0",
    "aggs": {
        "docs_groupName_in": {
            "terms": {"field": "groupName.keyword","include" : ".*India.*"}
        },
"docs_groupName_sl": {
            "terms": {"field": "groupName.keyword","include" : ".*Sri Lanka.*"}
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it does , it tells me the count of india and Sri lanka across my docs