# How to count the number of occurrence of keywords in results of elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to count the number of occurrence of particular keywords in the result set of a query. for e.g, I am trying the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "textlowercase": "bottle"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "textlowercase": "cow milk"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the above query will return me say N number of docs. Now is there any way to count the occurrence of the bottle and cow milk in these N docs, which were returned as a result for the above search query

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807472/how-to-count-the-number-of-keyword-matched-across-the-docs-in-es

Comment: @TomášLinhart it does not while other is about count of a keyword accross my data set and this is about count of keywords in the result set of . Both are totally different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
              "match": {
                "textlowercase": "bottle"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "textlowercase": "cow milk"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "docs_bottle": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "textlowercase",
        "include": "bottle"
      }
    },
    "docs_cow_milk": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fieldname.keyword",
        "include": "cow milk"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This issue is solved with the above query. However it does not count words that has more then one word e.g cow milk

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using aggregations.

```
{
    "size": "0",
    "aggs": {
        "docs_groupName_in": {
            "terms": {"field": "fieldname.keyword","include" : "bottle"}
        },
"docs_groupName_sl": {
            "terms": {"field": "fieldname.keyword","include" : "cow milk"}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no it does not, as the above will give you occurence of bottle and cow milk across all the docs. I need occurence of bottle and cow milk in the docs that were returened as a result of first query